# How to convert a mel spectrogram to log-scaled mel spectrogram

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, spectrogram, librosa

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04363.pdf) on environmental noise discrimination using Convolution Neural Networks and wanted to reproduce their results. They convert WAV files into log-scaled mel spectrograms. How do you do this? I am able to convert a WAV file to a mel spectrogram

```
y, sr = librosa.load('audio/100263-2-0-117.wav',duration=3)
ps = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)
librosa.display.specshow(ps, y_axis='mel', x_axis='time')
```

[image: mel spectrogram]

I am also able to *display* it as a log scaled spectrogram:

```
librosa.display.specshow(ps, y_axis='log', x_axis='time')
```

[image: log scaled image]

Clearly, they look different, but the actual spectrogram `ps` is the same. Using librosa, **how can I convert this melspectrogram into a log scaled melspectrogram?** Furthermore, what is the use of a log scaled spectrogram over the original? Is it just to reduce the variance of the Frequency domain to make it comparable to the time axis, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

`librosa.power_to_db` should do it, take a look at that