# How do I scale frequency axis of librosa spectrogram without using display.specshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib, librosa, spectrogram

### Context

I'm working on an audio classification problem and I want to recreate the spectrogram I get from `librosa's` built in plotting in grayscale.

The reason for doing this is to create images to pass to a neural network. Doing it with `Matplotib` is too slow, since it is designed for creating figures, not images.

I have scaled the amplitude using `power_to_db()`, but the frequency axis still needs to be scaled. With the built in `display.specshow()`, `y_axis='log'` I am able to replicate the desired result.

### Question

How can I apply an equivalent operation to my spectrogram so the `Y axis` of my image looks like the one provided by `librosa`? Consider comparing [librosa's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoGNc.png) spectrogram example and [mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwT7W.png).

```py
    def get_spectrogram_from_wav(wav: np.ndarray, sample_rate: int) -> np.ndarray:
        spec = np.abs(librosa.stft(wav))
        spec_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(spec, ref=np.max)
        # log_spec = np.log10(spec_db)
        
        return spec_db

    def plot_slice(wav: np.ndarray):
        spec = np.abs(librosa.stft(wav))
        plt.figure()
        
        librosa.display.specshow(
            librosa.amplitude_to_db(spec, ref=np.max),
            x_axis='time', y_axis='log'
        )
        
        plt.title('Power spectrogram')
        plt.show()
```

I believe the right way to do this per [Dorian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024701/obtaining-the-log-mel-spectrogram-in-python) is to create a `numpy meshgrid` using `np.logspace` for the `Y axis`. I'm still not sure what the next step should be, but this is a start.